# Build shared files with serverless typescript plugin

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, symlink, serverless

I'm using amazon lambda aws with serverless and the serverless-plugin-typescript to build my typescript files.
I have shared code in my project, e.g. a folder structure like this:

**/shared: shared1.ts, shared2.ts**

**/microservice1: microservice1.ts, serverless.yml**

**/microservice2: microservice2.ts: serverless.yml**

According to what I read it is not possible to pass a YAML file via command line to serverless deploy. So the current working directory has to be inside "/**microservice1**" or "/**microservice2**". This results in not being able to build with the following error:
'File '**...shared1.ts**' is not under 'rootDir' '...microservice1'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.' I also can not set rootDir in **tsconfig.json** to "../" since it is overwritten with default './'. So the only work around I see is to work with symlinks which is IMHO a little hacky.

So is there a possibility to build these shared files without using symlinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `serverless-webpack` since webpack can follow your imports and include them in your compiled file.

Comment: OK thanks that seems to solve the problem, simply because I can set "rootDir" in tsconfig now. Still a little stupid... Webpack now seems to generate a lot of Boilerplate code though. I also had to exclude node_modules to get rid of aws-sdk. Seems to work because aws-sdk is already present in the run time environment of Amazon Lambda...

Comment: @josh Feel free to mark this as an answer if this has helped you.